# Complexity of a code fragment

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  if(i < 2 || i > N - 3)
    for(int j = 1; j <= 10N; j++)
      a[i] = a[j - 1] / 2;
```

So the answer is `N(1 + 10N(1)) = n + 10n^2` right? or is it `n`?
Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an asymptotic upper bound... O(n^2). If you want to be pickier than that, we need to define computational weights for individual instructions.

Edit: Yeah, it's O(n). I read it wrong the first time.

Comment: Really? Of the three answers, you chose the incorrect one to accept? I would have gone with Gumbo for being right and explaining why.

Comment: Oh well. Yeah, at first I completely read "2 < i < N - 3"... which isn't what the OP wanted at all. I agree that my original answer is incorrect and that your and gumbo's answers are correct. At least we have correct answers to the OP's question... hopefully, the OP will get the gist.

Answer (score 4):

This looks `O(N)` to me.

The `if` statement is true for `i = 0,1,N-1,N-2`, which is a constant number of cases.

Answer (score 4):

Your conclusion is wrong. Although the outer `for` loops *N* times, the `if` condition is only true in 4 cases (0, 1, *N*-2, *N*-1). So the total run time is rather *N* + 4·10·*N* that is in O(*n*).